# Windows Azure: Is is possible to edit file in App_Data in cloud

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage, file-permissions

I am trying windows Azure cloud hosting.
I have deployed my application to cloud.

part of my application logic needs to edit a file in **App_Data** directory in cloud

When i try that function, it gives me error saying

> Access to the path is denied

This works perfectly in local.

So, here are my questions

1. Can i edit directory permissions on Cloud?
2. Is is a best practice to have editable content in App_Data directory?

App Environment: ASP.NET MVC 4.0 Razor View Engine

Comment: What file type is the file in question? Would it not be better placed in blob storage?

Comment: it is .json file type. That is my concern, if i have to choose blob for these files, as I will have more files added through application

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in files? Can you not store it in a database or something?

Comment: Well I can store in database. But I started this approach and wondering if I can make this work with json files.

Comment: Well, as the filesystem in Azure **can be a nightmare**, I'd suggest blob services for files, media services for audio/video, or in this case (for JSON), the database possibly.

Comment: Will check on blob storage and update here how it went. thank you.

Comment: No problem, let us know how it goes :)